# Use form.submitted after validation

Tags: angular, angular-template-form

I want to show a  button once a form has been submitted, however, it appears the validation counts as "Submitted" and doesn't `false` the value if validation fails.

My spinner is a partial

This results in my spinner button being shown, despite nothing being sent, because the form is submitted, but not valid.

Have I missed something?

```
 <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" [ngClass]="extraClasses" type="button" [disabled]="form.submitted" type="submit">
 {{text}}
 <span *ngIf="form.submitted" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" 
role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
```

Clicked submit with no details - validation fails, but still marks form as `submitted`
[image: Clicking submit with no details - invalid but submitted]

Passing validation now shows my spinner, but immediately (`submitted` true, `valid` true)

[image: After adding details, immediately spinning]

Comment: Why you have used two times the form name like ```form.form.invalid``` ?? I think it needs to be ```form.invalid```..

Comment: Updated - also updated in my code - no effect

Comment: If possible please create working example in stackblitz with the problem..

Answer (score 0):

Your submit button will be displayed even when the form is not valid, is it normal? If not, do :

```
<button *ngIf="!form.submitted && !form.form.invalid" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" [ngClass]="extraClasses"
  type="submit"> {{text}}</button>
```

**EDIT :**

You may want to create a property in your component ts file, for instance

```
private sumbitedWhenValid: boolean = false;
```

then set it to if the form is valid at the moment the form is submitted. For instance, if you have a http call, in the then() :

```
...then(() => {
    ...
    this.sumbitedWhenValid = !this.form.form.invalid;
});
```

then use it as a condition for you spinner :

```
<button *ngIf="sumbitedWhenValid" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" [ngClass]="extraClasses" type="button" disabled>
  {{text}}
  <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: That's right - I have two buttons - one that will always show, and one to show (with a spinner).

I feel it's bad UX to hide/show a button based on valid or not. But my issue is, if I "submit" and invalid form, then make it valid, my spinner button will show. Because the "Submitted" property gets set whether its invalid or not

Comment: Side Note: toggle the spinner on/off instead of toggling between 2 button elements

Comment: @KeenanDiggs why am I not doing this... 

Comment: Switched to the single button, the extra prop won't seems an anti-pattern - I have my button in a partial, but would I have to implement that on every form? Seem a bit backwards.